# Custom content management system - don't know how or when to escape content from db containing markup

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Im building a php cms and the content will be pulled from a mysql db.  How can I escape the content which has HTML markup and when should I do this?

Im just not sure how big an issue this is for main page content fields if only 'trusted' users can add content.

Thanks a lot in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you would want to use something like the htmlentities() function on the data when you are outputting it or the strip_tags() function.

The first defense though would be the only accept date in what format you are expecting. 
For example if it is a Name: field in a form you would only accept letters, spaces, ',-, and a few more characters. Don't add data into your database before checking if it is in the correct format.

Most form fields on a website do not required characters like < and > so don't let the data be added to the database without checking if it is in the correct format. If you are expecting a positive integer like the number 1,2,3,4... and so on don't let the script continue until those requirements are satisfied.

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly and your info. I'm thinking mainly about when a db column exists for content and it contains lots of 'p' tags. I usually use htmlspecialchars() but this ruins the markup. Id like to give trusted users ability to use js and custom attributes in main page content. Any thoughts?

Comment: With the strip_tags() function it takes a second arguement where you can tell it to allow certain html tags like this `strip_tags($content, '<p><a><script>'); and that will allow the <p> <a> and <script> tags but it will remove all the other ones. Hopefully that helps or can get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate you taking time out to help, whitelisting sounds like the way to go.